# App statistics are not updated daily

Tags: time, console, statistics, google-bigquery

I have some problems with the app-statistics in the Developer Console. In the FAQ, I could read that they are updated every day at 9:00. Today (8.June - 17.00) I can only see the statistics from 6. June. Why is there a time discrepancy of 2 days ?

Thanks for support.

Comment: They should be updating daily, are there still discrepancies? What's your timezone?

Answer (score 0):

I've a strange behaviour on my Google Developer Statistics because I've an application using google analitycs to know what countries are most used on my application. Today Google Analytics has 16 different countries, while Google Developer Console show me 5 different countries (both updated today).

Then I wander...how accurate is the information on Google Developer Console and why two different products of Google show me different values?